# How to use mysql Joins with paramerized query in Nodejs

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, node-mysql

I am working with Nodejs and expressjs,I am using "mysql2 library" and Right now i want to concat and use join (with paramerized) query , How can i do this ? I have following query and i want to write this query in express js (paramerized),How can i do this ?

```
SELECT `sd`.`service_id`, `sd`.`gender_type_id`, `sd`.`price`, `s`.`service_name`, concat('http://localhost/project/services/', s.image) as image, `s`.`time`
FROM `services_detail` `sd`
JOIN `services` `s` ON `sd`.`service_id`=`s`.`id`
WHERE `sd`.`id` = 13896
```

Comment: There's nothing different about using parameters in a join. Just replace the values that you want to parametrize with `?`.

Comment: E.g. `WHERE sd.id = ?`

Comment: @Barmar Kindly update/post the answer so i can check

Comment: Please post your attempt so I can help you fix the problem.

Answer (score 1):

If I understand you properly, you want to add a parameter into the query.
So just put the whole query inside `` and the parameter inside ${}.
for example:

```
let sample = 5;
let query = `SELECT * from table_name 
WHERE column_name = ${sample}`;
```

Comment: @diana If your question was about how to connect to the db by mysql2 or about another topic, let me know and I will Edit the post.

Comment: Yeah, that's it! Beware sql injections, but mysql and mysql2 have ways to deal with this issue, if that's the question being asked. I could not figure it out exactly too.